# json output and filename need to append in excel/csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have multiple `json` files inside`~/json-reports/`folder. One of the file format as follows.

**Filename:** `2728-daniel.json`

```
[
  {
    "depotFile": "//ABND/JJEB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "16",
    "perm": "open",
    "user": "5G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//LIB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "19",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "6G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//AND/RIO/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "20",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "AND_USER_GROUP"
  },
```

**Expected output in excel [or] csv as follows**

[image]

`port` and `user-id` need to be picked from `filename` of each file. Please help me out. Have tried various things couldn't help, Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are the user-id and port supposed to be derived from the 'depotFile' key value? I don't see how that could be obtained from your example

Comment: @BenWS Both `port` and `user-id` are not part of `json` output. they are part of `filename`

Comment: What did you try up to now? If you visit the help center you will probably see this question: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1773798), and this answer: [A lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1773798).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

paths = Path("json-reports/").glob("*.json")
dfs = {tuple(p.stem.split("-")): pd.read_json(p) for p in paths}
df = pd.concat([df.assign(port=p, userid=u) for (p, u), df in dfs.items()], axis=0)
print(df)

         depotFile host isgroup  line   perm            user  port  userid
0  //ABND/JJEB/...    *            16   open   5G_USER_GROUP  2728  daniel
1        //LIB/...    *            19  write   6G_USER_GROUP  2728  daniel
2    //AND/RIO/...    *            20  write  AND_USER_GROUP  2728  daniel
```

To get this in a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv("consolidated-reports.csv")
```

Comment: Getting this error. $ python3 output-into-csv.py
`Traceback (most recent call last):`
  `File "output-into-csv.py", line 6, in <module>`
    `df = pd.concat([df.assign(port=port, userid=u) for (p, u), df in dfs.items()], axis=0)`
  `File "output-into-csv.py", line 6, in <listcomp>`
    `df = pd.concat([df.assign(port=port, userid=u) for (p, u), df in dfs.items()], axis=0)`
`NameError: name 'port' is not defined` Something am i missing?

Comment: @Kishore There was a typo, in the list comprehension the variable is `p` and `u`, whereas in the `assign` call I was using `port` and `u`.

Comment: Thank you so much. it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually convert a json like this one to csv in few lines of code

```py
data = [
  {
    "depotFile": "//ABND/JJEB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "16",
    "perm": "open",
    "user": "5G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//LIB/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "19",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "6G_USER_GROUP"
  },
  {
    "depotFile": "//AND/RIO/...",
    "host": "*",
    "isgroup": "",
    "line": "20",
    "perm": "write",
    "user": "AND_USER_GROUP"
  },
]

title = ','.join(data[0].keys())
content = '\n'.join([','.join(x.values()) for x in data])
with open('out.csv','w') as f:
    f.write(title+'\n'+content)
```

Or you can use libraries like csv or pandas

---

If you want to do this with multiple json files then you just need the paths of each file.

```py
import json
paths = ['/home/yourname/jsonfiles/file1.json', ...]
for path in paths:
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        title = ','.join(data[0].keys())
        content = '\n'.join([','.join(x.values()) for x in data])
        with open(f'{path.remove('.json')}.csv','w') as c:
            c.write(title+'\n'+content)
```

Comment: i have multiple `json` files. automated way in `excel` or `csv` would be helpful.